# JSON deserializing in Spark with json4s causing package$MappingException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, json4s

I am trying to deserialize a simple JSON to a case class in Spark but getting an exception - the same code works in regular environment.

I am using the following version of json4s:

```
 "org.json4s" % "json4s-jackson_2.11" % "3.3.0"
```

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import scala.util.Try
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}

object TestParse {
  def run() = {

    val sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sconf)

    case class TestObj(name: String, value: String)

    val testData = sc.parallelize(List.range(1, 10))

    val dataObjsRDD = testData.map { val =>
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Workaround as DefaultFormats is not serializable
      Try { // Always results in Failure
        val jsonObj = parse("""{"name": "TheName", "value":"TheValue"}""")
        jsonObj.extract[TestObj]
      }
    }

    val d = dataObjsRDD.take(1)
    println(d)
  }
}
```

The exception I am getting is:

```
result = {Failure@7770} "Failure(org.json4s.package$MappingException: unknown error)"
 exception = {package$MappingException@7773} "org.json4s.package$MappingException: unknown error"
  msg = "unknown error"
   value = {char[13]@7846} 
   hash = 0
  cause = {NullPointerException@7779} "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   detailMessage = null
   cause = {NullPointerException@7779} "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[40]@7845} 
   suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@7781}  size = 0
  detailMessage = "unknown error"
   value = {char[13]@7846} 
   hash = 0
  Throwable.cause = {NullPointerException@7779} "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   detailMessage = null
   cause = {NullPointerException@7779} "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[40]@7845} 
   suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@7781}  size = 0
  stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[29]@7780} 
   0 = {StackTraceElement@7783} "org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:47)"
   1 = {StackTraceElement@7784} "org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)"
   2 = {StackTraceElement@7785} "TestParse$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestParse.scala:22)"
   3 = {StackTraceElement@7786} "TestParse$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestParse.scala:20)"
   4 = {StackTraceElement@7787} "scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)"
   5 = {StackTraceElement@7788} "TestParse$$anonfun$1.apply(TestParse.scala:20)"
   6 = {StackTraceElement@7789} "TestParse$$anonfun$1.apply(TestParse.scala:18)"
   7 = {StackTraceElement@7790} "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)"
   8 = {StackTraceElement@7791} "scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)"
   9 = {StackTraceElement@7792} "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)"
   10 = {StackTraceElement@7793} "scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)"
   11 = {StackTraceElement@7794} "scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)"
   12 = {StackTraceElement@7795} "scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)"
   13 = {StackTraceElement@7796} "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)"
   14 = {StackTraceElement@7797} "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)"
   15 = {StackTraceElement@7798} "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)"
   16 = {StackTraceElement@7799} "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)"
   17 = {StackTraceElement@7800} "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)"
   18 = {StackTraceElement@7801} "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)"
   19 = {StackTraceElement@7802} "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)"
   20 = {StackTraceElement@7803} "org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)"
   21 = {StackTraceElement@7804} "org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)"
   22 = {StackTraceElement@7805} "org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)"
   23 = {StackTraceElement@7806} "org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)"
   24 = {StackTraceElement@7807} "org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)"
   25 = {StackTraceElement@7808} "org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)"
   26 = {StackTraceElement@7809} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)"
   27 = {StackTraceElement@7810} "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)"
   28 = {StackTraceElement@7811} "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"
  suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@7781}  size = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a Spark issue, the problem is you've defined your case class in the method itself.  If you define the case class at the top-level (outside of the `TestScope` object) it should work.

See https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/125 for more information.